# Latex - unable to get proper boxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to get boxes with keywords after paragraphs. But the boxes are overlapping with previous lines and there is no spacing between boxes in latex[image]

This is the result I'm getting. Please help me with getting boxes below the lines and spaces between boxes

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Which LaTeX code gives this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly more catchy suggestions that uses the `tcolorbox` package to put the boxes around keywords. I also changed the keyword handling to a single `\keywords` command which takes a comma-separated list of keywords and puts each into an extra box. In case a keyword should include commas itself, put it into braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newtcbox\keywordbox{
    on line,
    colback=blue!10!white,
    colframe = blue!20!white,
    left = 0.2em,
    right = 0.2em,
    top = 0.2ex,
    bottom = 0ex,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    boxrule = 0.5pt,
    arc = 1pt,
}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{%
    \par
    \foreach \kw in {#1} {
        \keywordbox{\strut\textcolor{blue!20!black}{\kw}}
    }
    \par
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[2]
\keywords{Physical design, CMOS, Auto route, Timing delay, XYZ}

\item \lipsum[4]
\keywords{Cool \LaTeX\ stuff, $\mathrm{O}(n^\pi)$ complexity, {A, B, C}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, This was different

Comment: Hi, I used your code, but it worked only for first set of key words but form next set onwards it started overlapping with lines. What to do

Comment: @ChakrakeerthiReddy Please edit your question and add the problematic code to it. It's hard to tell what's wrong otherwise

Answer (score 4):

Since you provided no information about how you create the frames around the words and word groups, I feel free to start from scratch to offer a (hopefully) better solution.

- Be sure to insert the instruction `\par` before the line of boxed items.
- Use a custom macro -- called `\mybox`  in the code shown below -- to typeset the words and word groups. The `\mybox` macro makes sure that the boxes have the same heights. Be sure to leave at least one space between successive `\mybox{...}` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\newcommand\mybox[1]{%
    \begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}% default: 0pt (i.e., no extra space)
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}% default: 6pt
    \begin{tabular}{|l|} \hline #1 \\ \hline \end{tabular}%
    \endgroup}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum*[2] % filler text
\par % <-- important
\mybox{Physical design} \mybox{CMOS} \mybox{Auto route} \mybox{Timing delay} \mybox{XYZ}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked

Answer (score 4):

More simple and without any package: Use `\strut`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\def\mybox#1{\fbox{\strut#1}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\mybox{Physical design} \mybox{CMOS} \mybox{Auto route} 
\mybox{Timing delay} \mybox{XYZ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to add that it's very important to have a blank line before the group of `\mybox` instructions. (That, or insert a `\par` instruction...) By the way, while the `\strut` directive succeeds in making the boxes have equal heights and depths, it probably inserts *more than enough* vertical whitespace above the and below the words. A custom strut, with the height of an uppercase letter (say, `X`) and the depth of `p` (or `y`), would be more suitable to the task.

Comment: @Mico Said is! But I if there are more than one line of boxed words in the document (not clear, but the question mention  paragraphs, in plural ...) I think preferable have always the same box height that  have lines of boxes that could have different heights. Is the same bad effect that within lines, but between lines.

Comment: Just to clarify: I was *not* taking issue with the idea of inserting a typographic strut to assure that the boxes generated by `\mybox` have the same heights and depths. I was merely trying to point out that the strut inserted by `\strut` may be too tall. Defining `\def\customstrut{\rule[-0.45ex]{0pt}{2.1ex}}` and `\def\mybox#1{\fbox{#1\customstrut}}` may be more suitable -- unless, of course, the OP really really likes having lots of vertical whitespace inside the boxes! Aside: the values `0.45ex` and `2.1ex` are appropriate for Computer Modern, but likely not for other fonts.

Comment: Thanks a lot even this worked